# Writing a program for number of clicks in 1 hr/ 24 (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a click capping program- basically traffic control. (in PHP)

My goal is to log (to a text file) the number of clicks per hour (using an incremental counter). From there, I will write a program that redirects traffic based on whether the click cap has been met. So... to pseudocode it

```
if ($cap <= $currentCount){   //cap is the max, currentCount is the current click rate
    go here
}else{
    go here
}
```

The data I'm not sure how to access is $currentCount. Basically, it is the total number of clicks within a 24hr period. How do I log this?

How would I even begin to approach this? Any clues, hints, or tips? I'm pretty much in the dark about how to tackle this one.

:EDIT:

I have discovered a reasonable solution for this problem. I will highlight it below for anyone who encounters such a need in the future.

My company deals with buku amounts of traffic. As a result, we need a way to manage the excess, and direct it where needed. The goal was to write some sort of click counter that would allow us to maintain click caps (If we get the max number of clicks per day on one ad, and we don't want to waste our traffic by sending it to that site and those ads, we wanted to be able to redirect to another).

We are going to use Redis for this task, since the i/o of using a database in situations where traffic is extremely heavy would exhaust the db, and using a filesystem solution is out of the question for the same reason (and as described below, would result in file locking, and loss of click logging).

Something like this:

```
$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);

$redis->set('key', 'val');

echo $redis->get('key'); 
$redis->incr( 'counter', 1 ); // increment your counter
$counter = $redis->get( 'counter' );
if ( $counter > 100000 ) redirect( site1 );
redirect( site2 );
```

Thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: Your question needs some work. Are you asking how to read/write files in PHP?

Comment: I am asking how to log the number of clicks with in a 60 minute period. So... between now and 60 minutes from now, how many clicks were there? And say... between 45 min from now and 1hr 45 min from now.... how many clicks were there? My goal is to be able to determine at any time how many clicks there have been within the past hour.

Comment: you want clicks per hour, or per day? Do you care to store the previous values of the counter, or do you mean for it to be reset each time?

Comment: jegesh- I would ideally have separate counters- one that logs total clicks and persistently stores them, another that logs per hour and resets, and one more that logs per 24hrs and then resets.

Comment: Potentially an over-engineered solution but Ian Barber (of Google) implemented an event stream processing system which handles windows linked to time. Slides at https://speakerdeck.com/ianbarber/event-stream-processing-in-php

Comment: We typically like to see you try it first, then come to us instead of having us write your app for you. Do you specifically mean _"The last 24 hours"_ __or__ _"Made that day"_? (Is it from 00:00 on Day 1 to 23:59 Day 1, or from 12:00 Day 1 to 11:59 Day 2)

Comment: Jason- I definitely dont' want anyone to write it for me. Just an idea of where to start is all I'd like. And, to answer your question... I'm talking about "the last 24 hrs".

Comment: How about log the time clicks occurred in a database and then just run a simple `select` on the database to get the number of clicks that match X time requirements. You could easily store 24 hours worth of clicks and (depending on traffic) store years worth to look at. Pretty reasonable to add automatic delete for old times too. .. Same idea as logging to a text file I suppose, but databases are prittier ;)

Comment: @orchd That was a bit of an exaggeration, although the point is still solid. I'd recommend using a database for the same reasons that DACrosby mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a text file would be a pretty bad idea because of two things:

1. Concurrent access.  What if two users click at the exact same time? The lucky quickest one of those two will get the text file open and write to it. If there is file locking, the second one will fail to write because it couldn't get a lock on the file, or (if you write some complex stuff) it will wait and take up processing time until it can get its turn on the file.  If there are no file locks, both processes will open the same file at the same time, and only whichever one saves the file last will actually have its changes saved.  In essence, either only one of those users is going to get logged, or the second user experiences an annoying delay.
2. The file could get big.  And the bigger it is, the longer it will take both to add to the log and to retrieve the log.

Instead of using a text file, you should use a database table such as MYSQL.  It is really easy.  (If you use MYSQL, use mysqli or pdo.  DON'T USE mysql_* because it is deprecated.  There are lots of examples of mysql_* functions on the internet because they are old examples.  Don't use them.)

All you have to do is have some basic code that inserts a row into the database table each time someone clicks on your page.  This table should have a timestamp column, named something like ClickTime, that is set to automatically set itself to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP without you having to do anything.  If the only information you need is that a click occurred, you only have to say

```
INSERT INTO clicklogtable
```

If you needed to keep track of IP addresses, it would be more like

```
INSERT INTO clicklogtable (ClickIP) VALUE ('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

Then, you can ask the database to give you the number of rows within the last 24 hours easily:

```
 SELECT COUNT(ClickID) AS NumberOfClicks FROM clicklogtable
 WHERE ClickTime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

That "NumberOfClicks" value in there is your answer to the number of clicks in the last day.  The same syntax can get you your last hour, last 45 minutes, or any other time interval you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'd first of all start looking at jQuery.

The only way to actually capture mouse clicks would be client sided.On approach to that would be sending an AJAX request to the server on every click, or keeping track of a counter and sending that to the server every so many minutes, etc. But beware that client-sided approaches can be easily forged by others, thereby triggering your script even if it is not necessary.

However you might need to elaborate on what you exactly mean by clicks, since the above seems rather unlikely. In case you means access requests you could either

1. Parse the Apache access log file for requests in the last hour
2. Enter a entry into a database on every request
3. Write to a seperate file for every request

I'd recommend the first approach, since that'd have the least impact on your performance.

Hope I've answered completely :)

Comment: No mouse clicks. I mean access requests. So, parsing the apache access log file sounds like it makes the most sense.

Comment: If you redirect those requests to separate webhosts, maybe write a line into a text file using PHP and create a custom log, which resembles the apache access logs per redirect, that way you can track each redirect sepeartely

Comment: The apache access log stores all requests, including css, js, images, etc... so if you parse the log you should be sure to filter those out, otherwise one user click would net quite the offset.